# Cannot find object properties in an Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am currently learning JavaScript and I am having a horrible time with objects in an array.

I'm trying to find them. It won't find.

I'm trying display them, they are not displaying correctly.

I've been trying to figure this out for about 2 days and I'm lost

Here is the code

```js
const notes = [{
    title: 'The big trip',
    body: ' The next big trip will be back to thailand'
  },
  {
    title: 'Fitness goals',
    body: 'really enjoying the ab programme '
  },
  {
    title: 'life decisions',
    body: 'the move overseas '
  }
]

console.log(notes.length)

const findNote = function(notes, noteTitle) {
  const index = notes.findIndex(function(note, index) {
    return note.title === noteTitle
  })

  return notes[index]
}

const note = findNote(notes, 'Fitness Goals')
console.log(notes)
```

Comment: 1. It's `"Fitness goals"` with a lowercase **g**. You're calling `findNote(notes, 'Fitness Goals')` with an uppercase **G**. Change it to match. 2. You are printing `notes` instead of `note`. With those two changes your code works.

Comment: Just curious, why are you using `const` everywhere, instead of `let` (or `var`)?

Comment: @RocketHazmat why would `let` (or `var`) be needed?

Comment: @VLAZ I guess they wouldn't be... I just use `let` in my code, I've never had a use for `const`... I was just curious.

Comment: Why are you using `.findIndex()` instead of `.find()`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat `const` is for things that won't be reassigned. It makes it clear that this variable wouldn't change. Less mental load to keep track of when reading the code at the very least. `let` is for mutable bindings but if you never change them, it's kind of wasted. The worst things that could happen is an accidental bug if you do something like `let x = 1; if (x = 2)` but most of the time doesn't matter. I wouldn't choose `const` for the typo bug preventions, I use it because I don't have to mentally track if a variable changes or not.

Comment: Perfectly put by @RocketHazmat.  I'm using 'modern javascript' and 'var' is not used.  In modern JS we only use  'const' and 'let' in our coding.

Answer (score 5):

Your code is ok. Please check your function arguments here:

```
const note = findNote(notes, 'Fitness Goals')
```

There is no any note with title 'Fitness **G**oals'. Change this string to:

```
const note = findNote(notes, 'Fitness goals')
```

**'Goals'** and **'goals'** are different strings in Javascript, so program can't find any note